# json configuration of consul watch handler

Tags: consul

I'd like to run a script in sudo mode as my consul watch handler, I can run it with command

```
consul watch -type key -key mykey sudo -u myaccount /scripts/myscript.sh
```

But I don't know how to define it in json configuration, I've tried below but it does not works

```
{
  "watches":[{
    "type":"key",
    "key":"mykey",
    "handler_type":"script",
    "args":["sh","-c","sudo","-u","myaccount","/scripts/myscript.sh"]
  }]
}
```

I am using consul 1.5.2, this is the error:

> [ERR] agent: Failed to run watch handler '[sh -c sudo -u  myaccount /scripts/myscript.sh]': exit status 1

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my json configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the `sh -c`

I got it to work with:

```
"watches":[{
  "type":"key",
  "key":"mykey",
  "handler_type":"script",
  "args":["/bin/sudo","-u","consul","/bin/sh","-c","/home/testscript.sh"]
}]
```

The -c requires the script to be executable. Also you need the correct sudo privileges. You might even remove the `sh -c` altogether when the script is executable